# Error in prediction in digit recognition using cnn

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to predict the digit is 5 or not from 0 to 9.I have used cmaterdb dataset.

For this task I have changed all the digit label 0 except 5 in the training and test dataset

```
new_train_label=np.copy(train_labels)
for i, label in enumerate(new_train_label):
     new_train_label[i] = 0 if (label == 5) else 1

new_test_label=np.copy(test_labels)
for i, label in enumerate(new_test_label):
     new_test_label[i] = 0 if (label == 5) else 1

#train up model using cnn

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils



model = Sequential()

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(15, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.02))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_examples, new_train_label, epochs=30)

val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(test_examples,new_test_label)
print(val_loss)
print(val_acc)
```

Although accuracy is good, it can't predict 5. what is the wrong in my code or logic?

Comment: Please do not use bold without a reason for whole sentences (edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can guess, you have an accuracy of about 90%, but your model almost always predicts 0 ( not 5), right?

If it is the case, the reason can be the imbalanced classes. Your original dataset, I guess is balanced, like we have almost N 0s, almost N 1s, ... and almost N 9s. What you did, you kept the almost N 5s, and labeled it to 1, and turn the rest of almost 9*N examples to label 0. It means now you have 10% of data labeled 1( which are 5s) and 90% of data labeled 0. This is an imbalance case, and it is very normal you get a good accuracy of around 90%, but a poor prediction for the minority class. For imbalanced cases, accuracy is not a good metric or maybe it is not enough. Try to trace Precision,recall, and F1 as well.

my suggestion, sample from the non 5 classes ( 1/10 from each ) and keep all the 
5s. You should get better predictions.